# At what stage the training exactly takes place in FlannBasedMatcher in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, classification, kdtree, feature-descriptor

The following code is in C++ and I am using OpenCV for my experiment. Suppose I am using kd-tree (FlannBasedMatcher) in the following way:

```
//these are inputs to the code snippet below. 
//They are filled with suitable values
Mat& queryDescriptors;
vector<Training> &trainCollection;
vector< vector<DMatch> >& matches;
int knn;

//setting flann parameters
const Ptr<flann::IndexParams>& indexParams=new flann::KDTreeIndexParams(4);
const Ptr<flann::SearchParams>& searchParams=new flann::SearchParams(64);
FlannBasedMatcher matcher(indexParams, searchParams);

for (int i = 0; i < trainCollection.size();i++){
    Training train = trainCollection.at(i);  
    Mat trainDescriptors(train.trainDescriptors);
    trainDescriptorCollection.push_back(trainDescriptors);
}
matcher.add(trainDescriptorCollection);
matcher.train();

//Now, we may do knnMatch (or anyother matching) 
matcher.knnMatch(queryDescriptors,matches,knn);
```

In the above code it seems that training takes place (i.e. kd-tree is built) on calling the train() function. But here is the catch, if we look inside the train() function:

```
void FlannBasedMatcher::train()
{
    if( flannIndex.empty() || mergedDescriptors.size() < addedDescCount )
    {
        mergedDescriptors.set( trainDescCollection );
        flannIndex = new flann::Index( mergedDescriptors.getDescriptors(), *indexParams );
    }
}
```

Both of these operations (setting training descriptors and flann index, I have already done before calling train()). So when exactly is the kd-tree built?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the code calls FlannBasedMatcher::train(),the index of FlannBasedMatcher will be built by

```
flannIndex = new flann::Index( mergedDescriptors.getDescriptors(), *indexParams );
```

The code

```
if( flannIndex.empty() || mergedDescriptors.size() < addedDescCount )
```

is to check whether the index of FlannBasedMatcher has already been built before.If index has been built before,the train() function will skip the process of building index to save time.

Answer (score 2):

From [the documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/features2d/doc/common_interfaces_of_descriptor_matchers.html?highlight=descriptormatcher%3a%3atrain#void%20DescriptorMatcher%3a%3atrain%28%29), the training (i.e., in your cae builidng the kd-tree) is done every time before matching.
The `cv::DescriptorMatcher`class calls the training method automaticall when needed.

Comment: Yup. Thats what the documentation says. But as I have mentioned in the question, the train function does not really do anything other than dumping training descriptors into the relevant data structure within the class. So I could not trace where the kd-tree is actually built.