# Need information about opencv FlannBasedDetector

Tags: c++, opencv, flann

[From this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15047259/at-what-stage-the-training-exactly-takes-place-in-flannbasedmatcher-in-opencv) I have some questions that I can't find any answer.

The two more important ones are:

1) what does the two FlannBasedMatcher constructor arguments mean and how they modify Flann behavior.

2) From what I've read it is possible to save the trained data but I didn't understand much more than that.

I couldn't find documentation to answer neither of the questions above.